# HDR does not look good

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdr

After upgrading macOS to 10.15.4 on my Macbook Pro 2018, an HDR option shows up for my 4K BenQ PD3220U display.[image: Display options showing HDR] It is even pre-selected.

I can tell that the display is definitely in HDR mode. Unfortunately it does not look very good. The fonts are weird, as if they aren't antialiased. It is especially noticeable in black-on-white text.

Is there a way to improve the HDR mode?

The display is connected through USB-C. Changing resolution to `Default for display` does not help. I have used this display in HDR mode with ChromeCast Ultra so I know how good HDR can look.

Comment: My advice is to contact the device mfg.  it’s not that we don’t want to assist, but you might get exposure to a couple people with the same issue, but that doesn’t mean they have the answer.  The support staff deal with this every day do your chances of success are greater

Comment: @allan but I know that this display can display HDR beautifully, so it doesn't seem to me that it is the fault of the device.

Comment: I didn’t say “fault of the device”. I said they see it more often and can guide you to a solution.  They can do that even if it’s entirely  a macOS problem and fix.

Comment: Ok, I've contacted Benq support. I'll update the question with any advice they have.

Comment: Benq support advice has not been useful so far. But I'll update if I get anything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now realized that what I was seeing was the typical halo effect of high sharpenss. [The image examples in this article illustrates the effect perfectly](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/turn-down-your-tv-sharpness-control/).

Decreasing the sharpness from 10 (max, the default) to 1 (lowest) improved the fonts immensely. Even 5 is pretty good, but as far as I understand it sounds from forums like the lowest setting is most faithful to what the OS wants to display.